# Get perpendicular vector from another vector

Tags: unity, vector

I should clarify that I understand there is an infinite amount of 'perpendicular' vectors in 3D space. I am creating an electricity effect, and to do this the ability to have any number of perpendicular vectors is a good thing. The hard part is how to select any random one of these vectors - how would I do that, given a base vector "direction" which has been normalised?

Keep in mind that I want the resultant vector to be random, not just always up and down on the y-axis or anything.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a Unity-specific option in the same vein as [sam hocevar's answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/120982/39518):

```
Vector3 GetRandomUnitPerpendicular(Vector3 v)
{
    float angle = Random.Range(0, Mathf.PI * 2f);

    // Generate a uniformly-distributed unit vector in the XY plane.
    Vector3 inPlane = new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(angle), Mathf.Sin(angle), 0f);

    // Rotate the vector into the plane perpendicular to v and return it.
    return Quaternion.LookRotation(v) * inPlane;
}
```

By construction, this returns a unit vector. Rotating by a `Quaternion.LookRotation` is a bit overkill here, but it lets us pass off the problem of picking a basis to existing code, rather than duplicating it, keeping the code concise.

Note that these methods based on a random angle will have better uniformity than those based on generating a random vector in a square or cube (which have a higher probability of giving vectors pointing toward the corners than toward the sides), and don't need special handling for cases when the pseudorandom input is all zeroes.

Comment: This is arguably better than my answer. I think you could push the idea even further with something like: `return Quaternion.LookRotation(v) * Quaternion.AngleAxis(Random.Range(0, 360f), Vector3.forward) * Vector3.right;`

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

- have your vector **u** (ensure it’s normalised)
- pick an orthogonal vector **v** using *any existing method* (ensure it’s normalised)
- pick a random angle α
- a good random unit vector is therefore: **v**·cos(α) + (**u** × **v**)·sin(α)

If you wish your vector to also have random length, you can then multiply it by a random number, or possibly by *[the square root of a random number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskPointPicking.html)* depending on the kind of distribution you’re looking for.

Answer (score 1):

We know that the cross product of two vectors in 3-dimensional space is another vector which is orthogonal to both original vectors.

Given a vector which starts at the origin, we can just pick any random vector which starts at the origin to do the cross-product against.

Since the cross-product produces a vector which is orthogonal to both, and we picked a random vector as the second input, we have a vector which is both in a random direction and orthogonal to the original input vector.

**NOTE:** As DMGregory points out in the comments, you can sometimes select a random vector that is parallel to the original one. For this case, check if the result of the cross-product is a zero vector. If it is, then picking a random offset from the input vector *should* suffice.

**Example** *(JavaScript and THREE.js). The red arrow is the original direction vector, the green arrow the random orthogonal one. The blue circle is the plane orthogonal to the red arrow*:

```js
var con = document.getElementById('container');

var renderer, scene, camera;

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(320, 240);
con.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

scene = new THREE.Scene();

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 4 / 3, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.set(2, 1, 10);
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

function randPoint(){
  return Math.random() * 2 - 1;
}

// == Example ==
var vec1, vec2, vec3;

// Direction Vector
vec1 = new THREE.Vector3(2, 2, -2);
vec1.normalize();

// Random Vector
vec2 = new THREE.Vector3(randPoint(), randPoint(), randPoint());
vec2.normalize();

// Resultant Random Orthogonal Vector
// ===================================
vec3 = new THREE.Vector3();
vec3.crossVectors(vec1, vec2);

// Modify if needed. Offset vec1
// to ensure a vector which is not parallel.
if (vec3.x == 0 && vec3.y == 0 && vec3.z == 0){
  vec2 = new THREE.Vector3(
    vec1.x + Math.random() + 0.001,
    vec1.y + Math.random() + 1.001,
    vec1.z + Math.random() + 2.001
  );
  vec2.normalize();
  vec3.crossVectors(vec1, vec2);
}

vec3.normalize();
// ===================================

var origin = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);

var cGeo = new THREE.CircleGeometry(5, 32);
var cMesh = new THREE.Mesh(cGeo, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x0000ff, wireframe: true}));
cMesh.position.set(0, 0, 0);
cMesh.lookAt(vec1);
scene.add(cMesh);

scene.add(new THREE.ArrowHelper(vec1, origin, 5, 0xff0000));
scene.add(new THREE.ArrowHelper(vec3, origin, 5, 0x00ff00));


renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r73/three.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'></div>
```

Comment: This has a rare glitch if the generated `vec2` is parallel to `vec1` - then you'll get a zero vector for `vec3` which can't be meaningfully normalized.

Comment: @DMGregory true. In that case, one could check the cross product and modify the random vector if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for any vector that is completely in the plane described by a normal vector. Let's call your normal vector `n`, and the result vector (what you want to calculate) `r`. You know something about the relationship between the two vectors, namely that their dot product must be 0. That's one equation, but you have 3 unknowns here (the `x`, `y`, and `z` components of `r`). It turns out that's as much as you can constrain this problem. You will need to randomly select two coordinates in `r` and then project the last coordinate into the plane by using the dot product. Here's a simple solution (in pseudo-ish code since I'm not overly familiar with Unity):

```
Vector3 GetOrthogonalVector(Vector3 n) {
    Vector3 r(Random.value, Random.value);
    r.z = -(r.x*n.x + r.y*n.y)/n.z;
    return r.normalized;
}
```

Of course, you need to be safe and make sure that the `z` component of `n` (`n.z`) is not zero and do something sensible there. Also, as pointed out in the comments, if `r.x = r.y = 0`, then you will get zero for `r.z`, so that should be handled as well.

Comment: You'll also need to handle the rare case where `r.x = r.y = 0`, in which this method will generate a zero vector regardless of `n`.

Comment: Good point. Added a note.